# Run perl script from tcl

Tags: perl, unix, tcl

I have a perl script that I manually run it from shell:

```
myScript.pl -from_session=Session1234 -to_session=Session6789 -port=104:3445
```

I try to run it from tcl, in this way, but it doesn't work....

```
set script_path "myScript.pl";
set sessionA "Session1234";
set sessionB "Session6789";
set p "104:3445";
exec perl $script_path -from_session=$sessionA -to_session=$sessionB -port=$p
```

Update:

I found that the perl script is done, but the tcl script is not continue after the execution of the perl script.

Comment: Can you just use perl as a keyword without quotes there? I don't know much TCL but that looks wrong.

Comment: There is no reason _per se_ why what you wrote would not work. We need more details.

Answer (score 0):

TCL doesn't need semicolon at the end. Once removed, I tried to execute `exec` command on one of my PERL script in `tclsh` and it works fine.

Therefore my suggestion is to try executing the program in `tclsh` to see weather some error is returned and most importantly to give the full absolute path to the script. All in all, try

```
set script_path "/absolute/path/to/myScript.pl"
set sessionA "Session1234"
set sessionB "Session6789"
set p "104:3445"
exec perl $script_path -from_session=$sessionA -to_session=$sessionB -port=$p
```